# SQL Delete conditionally between rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with multiple rows for the same ID and I need to keep only one row with the following rules:

- NUM = 'AM' prevail on other
- If multiple NUM = 'AM' or none then the oldest date prevail

For example :

```
|_ID_|_NUM_|______DATE______|
| 99 | AM  |   2015-04-12   |
| 99 | QS  |   2012-05-31   |
| 99 | AM  |   2013-02-18   |
```

I need to keep the last row.

```
|_ID_|_NUM_|______DATE______|
| 99 | QS  |   2013-05-31   |
| 99 | QS  |   2016-02-18   |
```

I need to keep the first row.

I'm on a postgres database and I can't use Function or Procedure
Thank you for any help.

Comment: where does the `2016-02-18` come from? It is not in any of the three input records.

Comment: and how come `99 | QS  | 2012-05-31 `  becomes `99 | QS  |  2013-05-31`?

Comment: use the row_number()  window function : http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear, the data represents two different example. One the first one I only want the last row on result data and for the second I only want the first row on result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output data doesn't correspond to sample data, so i assume that you want to keep one row having `num = 'AM'` and `minimum date` or just `min date` if `num <> 'AM'` for every `id` and delete all other rows, so one way could be.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT t.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id
             ORDER BY (case when num = 'AM' then 1 else 2 end)
                ,DATE asc
            ) AS rn
    FROM table1 t
    )
DELETE
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM cte c
        WHERE t1.num = c.num
            AND t1.DATE = c.DATE
            AND t1.num = c.num
            AND c.rn <> 1
        );
```

**Result:**

```
id  num    date
------------------------------
99  AM     18.02.2013 00:00:00
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/TZJR68355)**

Answer (score 2):

[`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html). False orders before true.

```
select distinct on (id) *
from t
order by num <> 'AM', date
```

Comment: If I have asked this question. I must have accepted this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think this is what you seek:

```
with cte as (
  select
    id, num, date,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by num = 'AM' desc, date) as rn
  from foo
)
select
  id, num, date
from cte
where rn = 1
```